# Exit fullscreen when movie is done playing

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

I'm trying to implement a notification in to my movie player, so that once the movie is done playing, it will exit fullscreen. The code is have so far i posted below. The IBAction is hooked up to a button. Also on a side note, i have been trying to figure out how to get the "play symbol" on top of my movie view, so that the user just have to press that and the video will start. Anybody know how to implement that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Video player
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.navigationItem.title ofType:@"mov"];

    _player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: url]];
    _player.view.frame = CGRectMake(350, 200, 400, 400);
    [self.view addSubview:_player.view];
}

- (IBAction)playMovie
{
    [_player play];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect when your movie finishes playing by registering for an `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_player];
```

And then perform whatever action you want to do in the callback method you specified when registering:

```
- (void) playerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // movie finished playing
    _player.fullscreen = NO;
}
```